# Combine Two Queries With Different Join Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different queries that have the exact same `SELECT` and `WHERE` conditions but they have different `JOIN` conditions.

I am trying to find a way to combine both of these into one query and the only thing I've been able to come up with is to use a `UNION`. Is there a different or better way I can accomplish the same thing?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
create table #Account
(
    ID int, 
    FirstName varchar(25), 
    LastName varchar(25), 
    CodeA int, 
    CodeB int
)

create table #AccountMap
(
    CodeA int,
    CodeB int,
    MapType varchar(25)
)

insert into #Account 
values (1, 'Bob', 'Smith', 424, 867), (2, 'John', 'Davis', 543, NULL), (3, 'Mary', 'Brown', 654, 345)

insert into #AccountMap
values (424, 867, '1-1'), (543, NULL, 'A Only'), (654, 345, '1-1'), (NULL, 391, NULL)

-- Query #1
select ID, MapType
from #Account A
join #AccountMap M on M.CodeA = A.CodeA and M.CodeB = A.CodeB
where MapType is not null

-- Query #2
select ID, MapType
from #Account A
join #AccountMap M on M.CodeA = A.CodeA
where MapType is not null

-- Combined results
select ID, MapType
from #Account A
join #AccountMap M on M.CodeA = A.CodeA and M.CodeB = A.CodeB
where MapType is not null
union
select ID, MapType
from #Account A
join #AccountMap M on M.CodeA = A.CodeA
where MapType is not null

drop table #Account, #AccountMap
```

The desired output I am looking for is the result of the combined query in the example I provided (a distinct combination of both queries).

Comment: What's wrong with the query you already have? `UNION` returns a distinct dataset

Comment: @GordonLinoff I provided an example query with example data and desired results.

Comment: @Larnu nothing is wrong with it, I'm just wondering if there is a simpler and/or different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this?

This will give you the first when it exists and the 2nd when it doesn't.

```
Select ID, COALESCE(M1.MapType, M2.MapType) as MapType
from #Account A
left join #AccountMap M1 on M1.CodeA = A.CodeA and M1.CodeB = A.CodeB
left join #AccountMap M2 on M2.CodeA = A.CodeA
where COALESCE(M1.MapType, M2.MapType) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Select ID,MapType from #account a left Join #AccountMap b 
on a.CodeA=b.CodeA 
or a.CodeB=b.CodeB
```

Comment: you need a where statement to get rid of the null cases.